# date column right in komacv

Tags: cv

I'm using komacv (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/komacv) for my resume and want to move the dates column to the right side, similar to that: [How to move date column in moderncv?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211525/how-to-move-date-column-in-moderncv) (this only works for moderncv, not for komacv). Any ideas?

Btw. I cannot put the tag "komacv", because of lack of reputation.

Here is a simple example (derived from the example shipped with komacv):

```
\documentclass[%
]{komacv}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ifoot{CV~\firstname~\familyname}
\ofoot{\pagemark/\totalpagemark}
% ===========================
%    FONTS
% ===========================
\addtokomafont{firstnamefont}{\fontsize{35}{50}}

% ===========================
%    BIBLIOGRAPHY
% ===========================
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=ieee,%authortitle,% 
sorting=ydnt,%
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{komacv.bib}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[Publications]{\section{#1}}

% ===========================
%    PERSONAL DATA
% ===========================
\renewcommand*{\title}{CV}% PDF metadata
\renewcommand*{\firstname}{Jane}
\renewcommand*{\familyname}{Eyre}
\renewcommand*{\acadtitle}{B.\,Ed.}
\renewcommand*{\addressstreet}{Ferndean House}
\renewcommand*{\addresscity}{Ferndean Village}
\renewcommand*{\address}[2]{\addressstreet{#1}\addresscity{#2}}
\renewcommand*{\mobile}{009-87654321}


\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\maketitle

\section{Personal Information}
\cvitem{Date of birth}{February 15, 1828}

\section{Education}
\cventry{1835--1838}{Homeschooling}{}{Gateshead}{grades 1--3}{Teacher: Mr.~NN, under supervision of my aunt Ms. Reed.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note: `komacv` is not a KOMA-Script class. So the question is not related to KOMA-Script and I removed tag `koma-script`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Not included in the KOMA bundle, but it uses KOMA-script internally. I would have left the tag.

Comment: @Johannes_B: But the question is not about a KOMA-Script feature. It's about using `komacv`. Or would you set the tag `latex-kernel` for all questions about packages, that use the LaTeX kernel internally?

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on the version of `komacv`. Below you find patches for the versions `2014/08/10 v1.0.1` and `2017/04/17 v1.1.1`.

---

**komacv version 2014/08/10 v1.0.1:** Add the following lines before `\begin{document}`:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\origcvitem\cvitem
\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][\@afterelementsvspace]{%
  \begin{tabular}{%
      @{}p{\@maincolwidth}%
      @{\hspace{\@sepcolwidth}}p{\@hintscolwidth}@{}%
    }%
    {#3} & \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2}%
  \end{tabular}\\[#1]%
}
\renewcommand\@cvbarsection[1]{%
  \origsection*{
    \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    \origcvitem[0pt]{%
      \raggedleft\hintstyle{\color{@secbarcolor}%
        \rule{\@hintscolwidth}{1ex}}%
    }{\sectionstyle{#1}}
  }% end origsection
} % end cvbarsection
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[%
]{komacv}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ifoot{CV~\firstname~\familyname}
\ofoot{\pagemark/\totalpagemark}
% ===========================
%    FONTS
% ===========================
\addtokomafont{firstnamefont}{\fontsize{35}{50}}

% ===========================
%    BIBLIOGRAPHY
% ===========================
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=ieee,%authortitle,% 
sorting=ydnt,%
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{komacv.bib}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[Publications]{\section{#1}}

% ===========================
%    PERSONAL DATA
% ===========================
\renewcommand*{\title}{CV}% PDF metadata
\renewcommand*{\firstname}{Jane}
\renewcommand*{\familyname}{Eyre}
\renewcommand*{\acadtitle}{B.\,Ed.}
\renewcommand*{\addressstreet}{Ferndean House}
\renewcommand*{\addresscity}{Ferndean Village}
\renewcommand*{\address}[2]{\addressstreet{#1}\addresscity{#2}}
\renewcommand*{\mobile}{009-87654321}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\origcvitem\cvitem
\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][\@afterelementsvspace]{%
  \begin{tabular}{%
      @{}p{\@maincolwidth}%
      @{\hspace{\@sepcolwidth}}p{\@hintscolwidth}@{}%
    }%
    {#3} & \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2}%
  \end{tabular}\\[#1]%
}
\renewcommand\@cvbarsection[1]{%
  \origsection*{
    \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    \origcvitem[0pt]{%
      \raggedleft\hintstyle{\color{@secbarcolor}%
        \rule{\@hintscolwidth}{1ex}}%
    }{\sectionstyle{#1}}
  }% end origsection
} % end cvbarsection

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\maketitle

\section{Personal Information}
\cvitem{Date of birth}{February 15, 1828}

\section{Education}
\cventry{1835--1838}{Homeschooling}{}{Gateshead}{grades 1--3}{Teacher: Mr.~NN, under supervision of my aunt Ms. Reed.}


\end{document}
```

---

**komacv 2017/04/17 v1.1.1:** Add the following lines before `\begin{document}`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][\@afterelementsvspace]{%
  \begin{tabular}{%
      @{}p{\@maincolwidth}%
      @{\hspace{\@sepcolwidth}}p{\@hintscolwidth}@{}%
    }%
    {#3}&\RaggedLeft\hintstyle{#2}%
  \end{tabular}\\[#1]%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[%
]{komacv}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ifoot{CV~\firstname~\familyname}
\ofoot{\pagemark/\totalpagemark}
% ===========================
%    FONTS
% ===========================
\addtokomafont{firstnamefont}{\fontsize{35}{50}}

% ===========================
%    BIBLIOGRAPHY
% ===========================
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=ieee,%authortitle,% 
sorting=ydnt,%
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{komacv.bib}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[Publications]{\section{#1}}

% ===========================
%    PERSONAL DATA
% ===========================
\renewcommand*{\title}{CV}% PDF metadata
\renewcommand*{\firstname}{Jane}
\renewcommand*{\familyname}{Eyre}
\renewcommand*{\acadtitle}{B.\,Ed.}
\renewcommand*{\addressstreet}{Ferndean House}
\renewcommand*{\addresscity}{Ferndean Village}
\renewcommand*{\address}[2]{\addressstreet{#1}\addresscity{#2}}
\renewcommand*{\mobile}{009-87654321}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][\@afterelementsvspace]{%
  \begin{tabular}{%
      @{}p{\@maincolwidth}%
      @{\hspace{\@sepcolwidth}}p{\@hintscolwidth}@{}%
    }%
    {#3}&\RaggedLeft\hintstyle{#2}%
  \end{tabular}\\[#1]%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
\maketitle

\section{Personal Information}
\cvitem{Date of birth}{February 15, 1828}

\section{Education}
\cventry{1835--1838}{Homeschooling}{}{Gateshead}{grades 1--3}{Teacher: Mr.~NN, under supervision of my aunt Ms. Reed.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I get this error, do I need to include something?

! Undefined control sequence.

    \\cvitem ...\@hintscolwidth }@{}}{#3}&\RaggedLeft 

                                                  \hintstyle {#2}\end {tabul...

    l.51 \section{Personal Information}

When I let it run till the end, the dates are on the left, but the blue bars as well. Is it possible to have the blue bars on the left like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211525/how-to-move-date-column-in-moderncv ?

Comment: @user188311 This is a version mismatch: My solution was for the recent version of `komacv.cls` (from today), which does not work for the previous version. I've now also added a solution for the previous version, see my answer.